# Bootstrap: Exists a documentation for the default color variables?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, less

I want to create a custom bootstrap theme. Modify the [variables.less](http://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/less/variables.less) is the best way I know to do this. But each time I did this, I am annoyed about the color variables `@gray*`. They will be used for the components in different ways.

Currently I delete them, create my own color variables and go trough the code and replace the `@gray*` variables by my own.

I tried to modify the `@gray*` variables and create a custom theme without any own color variables, but the results I got was not as good. Exists any documentation that explains what the `@gray*` variables are used for?

Thank you!

---

**Update**

To be more specific, here is an example what I am looking for:

```
@gray
- button border color
- table text color
@gray-dark
- well text color
- label background color
- ...
```

Comment: Please stop tagging "bootstrap": *bootstrapping refers to the process of loading the basic software into the memory of a computer after power-on or general reset, especially the operating system which will then take care of loading other software as needed* - Wikipedia

Comment: @DanielCheung Tag removed.

Answer (score 1):

Look here: http://getbootstrap.com/customize/

It shows you exactly what happens with the @Gray variables.

Kind Regards,
Josh

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I know this page and the explanation of the `@gray*` variables is not specific enough. I also know pages like http://bootswatchr.com/. My porblem is, that I have to invest a lot of time by check my changes and to be sure that the correct components will be changed.